# How to globally number pages automatically in LaTeX?

Tags: page-numbering

I am new to LaTeX so definitely naïve in this topic. How do I number each pages automatically in LaTeX. The current page numbering is carried out on a chapter basis. It would restart the counter in next chapter and begin numbering again. So, how can I maintain a global counter that counts page from the first page all the way to the last? My document class is `report`.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
```

---------------------I am update line -----------------------

```
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3.5cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

% graphics images
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

% 1.5 line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

% maths symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}

% table package
\usepackage{multirow}

% source code listing
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}


% citation style
\usepackage{apacite}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}

\begin{document}


% cover
\input{cover_report.tex}

% title page
\input{title_report.tex}

% abstract
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{abstract.tex}

% acknowledgement
\input{acknowledgements.tex}

% table of content
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

% list of tables
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

% list of figures
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{intro.tex}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{background.tex}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{design.tex}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{implementation.tex}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{analysis.tex}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{limit_future.tex}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{conclusion.tex}

% references
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{my_ref}

% appendix
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The page numbering system you currently have is not standard for the `report` document class. Some macros in your preamble and/or some LateX package you're loading must be modifying the page numbering system. Please post an MWE (minimal working example) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

Comment: Great good to know that Mico.I've updated my question and attached the code. let me know if that suffice to diagnose the problem

Comment: you need to set `\pagenumbering{arabic}` only the first time (for your intro.tex chapter) and remove the other occurrences

Comment: Yeah that's right. I should remove them. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

This is a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}           %this causes the page numbering reset
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The solution is to load `\pagenumbering` only once, when you want to switch between roman and arabic numbering.