# Continuous page numbering in a thesis document

Tags: page-numbering

I am using a thesis template but by problem is that I need continuous arabic numbering starting at title page, all the way through the thesis. But it resets at chapter 1.. This is what I have for the main part that calls the chapters

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,times,authoryear,oneside,print,PageStyleII]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{setspace}

\input{Preamble/preamble}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% ************************ Thesis Information & Meta-data **********************
% Thesis title and author information, refernce file for biblatex

\input{thesis-info}

% ******************************** Front Matter ********************************
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\let\oldthispagestyle=\thispagestyle % If we want to see a page number.
\def\thispagestyle#1{} % If we want to see a page number.


\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{titlepage}


\begin{titlepage}
 \maketitle
\end{titlepage}


\include{Dedication/dedication}
\include{Declaration/declaration}
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
\include{Abstract/abstract}`

% *********************** Adding TOC and List of Figures ***********************

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables


% ******************************** Main Matter *********************************
\mainmatter


\input{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
\include{Chapter3/chapter3}
\include{Chapter4/chapter4}
\include{Chapter5/chapter5}
%\include{Chapter6/chapter6}
%\include{Chapter7/chapter7}


% ********************************** Bibliography ******************************
\begin{spacing}{0.9}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{References/references} % Path to your References.bib file
\end{spacing}

% ********************************** Appendices ********************************

\begin{appendices} % Using appendices environment for more functunality

\include{Appendix1/appendix1}

\end{appendices}

% *************************************** Index ********************************
\printthesisindex % If index is present

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I don't believe that this document compiles! Most of the content is hidden in `\include` or `\input` statements of files we have no access to! And `\renewenvironment{titlepage}` is wrong!

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: may be if you don't use frontmatter and mainmatter you will be fine

Comment: I suspect that you have the command `\pagenumbering{arabic}` in every chapter.  It should only be ONCE in the document before you input or include other parts.  And it must NOT be in any other file you input.   See this for a MWE illustrating the problem and solution.   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149284/how-to-globally-number-pages-automatically-in-latex

Comment: Can you add a link to the document class?

Comment: At least start by removing `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` as @touhami suggests since we *know* they will reset page numbers and switch between roman and arabic. (At least, the first 2 do. I don't recall what `\backmatter` does.)

Answer (score 4):

The class is based on `book` and it's sufficient to modify the definitions of `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.

The trick you use for reinstating the page number in the table of contents is terrible! I suggest another one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,times,authoryear,oneside,print,PageStyleII]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just to fill in nonsense text

% modify \frontmatter and \mainmatter to have continuous numbering    
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage\@mainmatterfalse
}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage\@mainmattertrue
}
\makeatother

% reinstate the page number in the initial page of TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{plain}}%
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Abstract}
\kant[1]

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables


\mainmatter

\chapter{Main}

\kant

\end{document}
```